# What are the things to keep in mind while replacing the MCU with a pin compatible MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, stm32cubemx

I am swapping a pin-compatible STM32 MCU from STM32F0 to STM32F4 which is a transition from Cortex-M0 to Cortex-M4. I will have to migrate the F0 based STM32 library to STM32F4 one to ensure the peripheral work. I also plan to upgrade the clock speed. Apart from these, what are the general and common list of activities and risks I must keep in mind?

Comment: It's mainly differences in the peripherals. Sometimes the names might be a bit different too even if everything else is the same. Going from F3 to G4 or H7, the clock set up is very different.

Comment: Upgrading the clock speed would probably occupy most of my thinking time, I suspect. Most of the risks are there, given that you feel you have the library issues in hand with respect to peripherals.

Comment: The whole linker script needs to be changed, obviously. You will have no make a fresh project for the M4 version. As for clock speeds, check if you need to add flash wait states.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check what pin compatible really means. Simply replacing the MCU for another one in same package may not work, unless the hardware around the MCU is designed or changed to work with both MCUs or the new MCU.

One thing to check is that all power supply pins compatible without changes and are all peripherals available on same pins and are the same pins 5V tolerant if they need to be.

It also means the bootloader if you use it. A larger MCU might have more interfaces for boot loader, so more pins are required to stay stable so that it does not select the wrong interface instead of the intended interface.

And other hardware requirements, such as current consumption, bypass cap size and placement, and crystal oscillator parameters. A new higher speed MCU may not work in place of the old MCU if it now needs better PCB design than old MCU.

The new MCU that is faster has stronger and faster output drivers. So the hardware around the MCU must be able to work with an MCU that can generater faster signal edges, even if signal frequency is identical. This may lead to problems with EMC/EMI unless taken care of.

So basically, if that is a product you are selling, it can basically be considered as a new product and should be re-tested that it still fills the regulations.